# Hello this is my first time creating a procedure but I keep getting the SQL STATEMENT IGNORED error. Any help would be appreciated

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

**My Procedure** 

[image: Procedure]

**The errors I am getting.**
[image: errors]

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: Okay that's good info  I will do this next time. I am new to Stack so I don't know the process yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check your schema.table_name.   On your insert statement, you have MEMBER_ONLY yet on your update, you have MEMBERS_ONLY (Plural).

Also, if I am not mistaken the top part is also incorrect.

CREATE PROCEDURE procedurename
(
@paramname int
)

As

Comment: You are mistaken. This is Oracle, its parameters don't look like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is, obviously, Oracle.

Error stack points to exact error place, e.g.

```
Error(22,29): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist     
      -- --
      ^   column 29
      |
      line 22
```

It would be easier to spot it if you chose to display line numbers in SQL Developer (do so; right-click the left margin and set it). I'd say that it is about `member_system.member` table. Another one, in the same `from` clause, is `prospect_staging.magi_applicant`.

It is unclear which user you're connected to (one, or none of these), but - comment you posted in deleted answer:

> It works in the workbench but when I place it in the procedure it says the table or view isn't created

suggests that you might have got access to the table via **role** (and not directly to your user). Why? Because privileges acquired via roles work at SQL level or in anonymous PL/SQL blocks, but won't work in named PL/SQL procedures or functions - and that's what you have, a procedure named `get_magi_applicant_data`.

So, what to do? Grant privileges directly.

---

As of another error you got:

> Error(31,9): PLS-00201: identifier 'V_INSERT_OR_UPDATE' must be declared

Looks like it is about `if v_insert_or_update is null then` line. Error isn't obvious; there is `v_insert_or_update` local variable declared in the procedure, so I can't guess what might be wrong here.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I thought as well. It might be a permission issue. I am going to talk to my supervisor tomorrow.

Comment: I was wondering would a permission issue still be the problem if I can make a procedure with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE('Hello world'), but not access the tables?

Comment: The only permission problem in that case would be the fact that you weren't granted the CREATE PROCEDURE privilege. Other than that, no, as DBMS_OUTPUT package is granted to PUBLIC (read: everyone).